# Load CSV to multiple tables solving key constraint issues

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In MySQL, is it possible to load a CSV into a stored procedure which in-turn will be populating multiple tables, each having foreign-key dependencies Exl - table1's primary key to be used in table2, and table2's primary key to be used in table3?

Example - 
A single file with 5 columns to be read in a stored procedure, 
Per every line / record in the CSV file, use column1 and column2 to insert in table1, get the primary key, and then insert column 3 and column4 in table 2, get the primary key and use table1's primary key and table2's primary key and coulmn5 to be inserted in table3

I am considering the following Options -

1. Have an external application which reads the CSV, and passes the
   data [every row in CSV] to a stored procedure with prepare statements, which will take
   care of subsequent inserts into the required tables.
2. Load the CSV
   into a temp table, and have a stored procedure with prepare
   statements, which will take care of subsequent inserts into the
   required tables.
3. Have an external application which reads the CSV,
   and have a set of prepared statements to insert into subsequent
   tables. However, getting the primarykey externally and then re-using
   will cause delays..

Re-phrased the question to know the performance efficient approach to this issue, and if it is possible to load the CSV, how do we do it?

Comment: Do you mean to execute LOAD DATA INFILE several times, for each table? When tables data are stored in different files.

Comment: No, a single file with 5 columns to be read in a stored procedure, 
Per every line / record in the csv file, use column1 and column2 to insert in table1, get the primary key, and then insert column 3 and column4 in table 2, get the primary key and use table1's primary key and table2's primary key and coulmn5 to be inserted in table3

Comment: It is not trivial task. There is one idea, but I should try it;)

Comment: Can you show your CSV, some lines for example? Does it contain ID values?

Comment: Yes. Now, I am now planning to have the ID's [Primary keys] forced and not AUTO_INCREMENT, else it is slowing down considerably. 

Example line - 

1000000024,PDT2342,35,1424838470000,1577750400000,45,SK2342_543,1,true,0,USR23
1000000025,PDT1342,35,1424838470000,1577750400000,45,SK1342_54,1,true,0,USR23

Comment: The solution depends on csv format. If you are planning to change csv, why don't you split it to 3 different csv-files?

Comment: Not planning to change the CSV. Planning to change the approach of solution being taken up.

Comment: Not planning to change the CSV. Planning to change the approach of solution being taken up.

1. From external application, tried separate inserts, and it is taking more time
2. From external application, tried with Stored Procedure, and it is taking more time than the approach #1.
3. Thought of directly loading CSV into a temp table, and then to use stored procedure to populate to individual tables. However, since #2 itself was taking time, planning to ignore this approach.
4. From external app, build three different CSVs from source and load them directly using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple approaches as stated above, found an optimal way. Have split-up the overall tasks into two main parts - Splitting the Data, Loading the Tables

- **Split** - External application to split up the source file into multiple CSVs [matching the schema of table1, table2 and table3]
- **Load** - Use **LOAD DATA INFILE** which is the fastest way to populate tables.

[For all these tables, hard-code the primary key insteading of depending on AUTO_INCREMENT]

Thanks all for your input, suggestions and directions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it can be done.  I'm not convinced it should be done this way as it is putting a lot of business logic into the database and that is generally considered to be a bad thing.  This is much easier and better done in an application outside of the database.

But - the question was can it be done.  I'd do this by loading the CSV into a temporary table (as it doesn't look like there is a way to read line by line in a stored procedure).  Then you can iterate over all the rows in the table and do what you need to do.

Hope that gives you a clue to get you going.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The approach of loading into temporary table was taken up, however, we wanted to consider the time it would take when loading via external application vs a stored procedure issuing insert statements. Volume of data being discussed is around 20-25 million records as source csv.

Could you please suggest a performance efficient approach?

Comment: I would do it in an external application and use prepared statements - this would mean MySql would only need to optimise the query one time - and then you can use it millions of times.

Comment: I am considering the following Options -
1. Have an external application which reads the CSV, and passes the data to a stored procedure with prepare statements, which will take care of subsequent inserts into the required tables.
2. Load the CSV into a temp table, and have a stored procedure with prepare statements, which will take care of subsequent inserts into the required tables.
3. Have an external application which reads the CSV, and have a set of prepared statements to insert into subsequent tables. However, getting the primarykey externally and then re-using will cause delays..

Comment: The application and a stored procedure would be getting the last insert id in the same way - any delay in doing this from the application rather than within a stored procedure is insignificant - in any good mysql client library it will be part of the results object.

You should also structure the application to maximise the number of times you use the prepared statement before needing to prepare a new one.

Comment: You suggest #1? I am inclined towards #2, reducing the hop from external application to mysql

Comment: You will not see any significant performance improvement over using properly parameterized queries - you will just make life much more difficult for yourself developing this application.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, see [Appendix C1 - Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) which tells you that LOAD DATA cannot be used in a stored routine.

> SQL Statements Not Permitted in Stored Routines
>
> Stored routines cannot contain arbitrary SQL statements. The following
>   statements are not permitted:
>
> The locking statements LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES.
>
> ALTER VIEW.
>
> ***LOAD DATA and LOAD TABLE.***

Again, in the [documentation for prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) you'll find that it says the following

> Generally, statements not permitted in SQL prepared statements are
>   also not permitted in stored programs.

and then gives a helpful list of permitted statements. Unfortunately, you won't find the same list in the documentation for stored programs (where it might be more useful).

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution. You can use some auxiliary triggers. Suppose that you insert data (or load from the file) into **main** table. Then you have **table1(c1, c2)**, **table2(c3,c4)** and **table3(c5)**, as in your question.

Now:

1. we are using **trigger1** on **main** table to insert data into **table1**. Some session variables are being used to store temporary field values.
2. we are using **trigger2** on **table1** table to insert data into **table2**
3. we are using **trigger3** on **table2** table to insert data into **table3**

Let's look at the script:

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  c1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c3 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c4 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c5 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_ref_table1 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c3 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c4 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;

CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_ref_table2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c5 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE main (
  c1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c3 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c4 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  c5 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 30;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON main
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @c3 = NEW.c3;
  SET @c4 = NEW.c4;
  SET @c5 = NEW.c5;

  INSERT INTO table1 (c1, c2)
    VALUES (NEW.c1, NEW.c2);
END
$$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2 (id_ref_table1, c3, c4)
    VALUES (NEW.id, @c3, @c4);
END
$$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger3
AFTER INSERT
ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table3 (id_ref_table2, c5)
    VALUES (NEW.id, @c5);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And some INSERT statements with result:

```
INSERT INTO main(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) VALUES
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
('11', '22', '33', '44', '55');


SELECT id, c1, c2 FROM table1;
------------------------------
10  1   2
11  11  22

SELECT id, id_ref_table1, c3, c4 FROM table2;
---------------------------------------------
20  10  3   4
21  11  33  44

SELECT id, id_ref_table2, c5 FROM table3;
-----------------------------------------
30  20  5
31  21  55
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried this out, however, LOAD DATA INFILE is faster than this approach

Comment: Of course simple LOAD DATA is fast. We are just trying to make a SQL-solution with minimum requirements. You should change `INSERT INTO main...` with `LOAD DATA...INTO TABLE main...` statement.